# Detect keyup on winform without any control

Tags: c#, winforms, onkeyup

As stated in title, I have a form that doesn't have any control on itself (so I can't focus it!!! damn).

I keep it controlless because I need to show images on background and I need to move it by keeping mouse clicked.

Are there any way to detect the keyup event when this is the foreground window?should I use a global hook (and check which is the foreground image obviusly)?

Any simplier workaround?I tested with an hidden control but it's not working.

The problem of putting a control with opacity = 0 brings the possibility to "miss" the MouseDown and MouseUp events (because they could happen over the control instead of the form, but I can still redirect them)

Any suggestion?

Here is the question where I picked some resources:
[Fire Form KeyPress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499463/how-to-fire-form-keypress-event)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just set the Form's [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) to `true` and use the Form's [`KeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) Event? (or am i missing something?)

Comment: I tested with it because was the fastest solution, however **after** I click one time on the form the events stops being fired, can't understand why

Comment: I understood the problem: the window must be the foreground one, I just set it when mouse pass over it (which is the behaviour I wanted, so it's not a problem for me). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would override OnKeyUp as it seems to be exactly what you are asking for.  Here is an example of popping up a Message Box when the Escape key is released.

```
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Escape was pressed");
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        base.OnKeyUp(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are seeking for GlobalHook. Please have a look at [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Native Api. You can easily write your [Pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowsHookEx.html) statements.
Here is an example from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowsHookEx.html)

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyClass
{
     private HookProc myCallbackDelegate = null;

     public MyClass()
     {
     // initialize our delegate
     this.myCallbackDelegate = new HookProc(this.MyCallbackFunction);

     // setup a keyboard hook
     SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD, this.myCallbackDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
     }

     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     protected static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType code, HookProc func, IntPtr hInstance, int threadID);

     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

     private int MyCallbackFunction(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
     {
    if (code < 0) {
        //you need to call CallNextHookEx without further processing
        //and return the value returned by CallNextHookEx
        return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
     // we can convert the 2nd parameter (the key code) to a System.Windows.Forms.Keys enum constant
     Keys keyPressed = (Keys)wParam.ToInt32();
     Console.WriteLine(keyPressed);
    //return the value returned by CallNextHookEx
    return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, code, wParam, lParam);
     }
}
```