# Key press event and button event conflict

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express to write a Window Form Application.  I am writing a Sudoku program.  I have written this program once before and got it working.  I lost the source code due to a hard drive failure.  I got a grid drawn on the form.  I got the mouse event to work.  I got key press event to work.  I then I added several buttons to the form and got them to work.  But then a problem occurs.  After I added the buttons and got them working, the key press event stops working.  Why is there a conflict between the button event and the key press event?

Here is the Code for a demo program that has the same problem.
‘code’
        private void doMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int i;
            i = 0;
        }

```
    private void DoKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)\\   This worked until I added
    {
        int i;
        i = 1;
    }

    private void doClickButton(object sender, EventArgs e)   \\   This
    {
        int i;
        i = 2;
    }
```

‘code’

The mouse event and keypress event was added to the form.

Looks like I need a way to set the focus on the form.  The program will need to go back and forth between the mouse and the keyboard before the button is used.

Comment: Please can you show us code for those events in order to help you

Comment: What did you add the key event to? The form? Have you verified that the events are still there and that you didn't accidentally remove them?

Comment: I would guess, the object, you added the KeyPress event handlers to, does not have the keyboard focus any more. Maybe PreviewKeyDown will help you.

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499463/fire-form-keypress-event

Answer (score 0):

Set your forms [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property to true

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```