# How to make wav file play when I press the letter 'Q'

Tags: c#

```
SoundPlayer my_wave_file = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources._01);
my_wave_file.Play();
```

Above is my code for the wav file to play. I want it to play when I press the letter 'Q' on the keyboard while it is loaded up on the form load doing nothing.

Purpose is to make a piano if that helps. So I'm going to assign each letter with a different wav file.

I'll also accept any other ways to do this.

Comment: @ M.kazem Akhgary Thank you. The second link did it for me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499463/fire-form-keypress-event                        This helped but now I have a problem making it work for multiple keys...

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out